# Image to Base64 using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I used this function after geting picture from camera. 
It always console me same data. data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAEsCAYAAACG+vy+AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAQBJREFUeJztwTEBAAAAwqD1T20LL6AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgIcBqtkAAcZpLS4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

```
 function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.src=imageURI;


      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute('width',200);
      canvas.setAttribute('height',300);

      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 29, 0, 142, 300);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

console.log(dataURL);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Every Time I get this base64 on every image that is wrong base64

Comment: have you tried `console.log(imageURI)` at the beginning of your function? I would start there and make sure that this value is what you are expecting each time.